# Unexpected let, use const instead

Tags: typescript, tslint

I got `no-let` rule in `tslint` configuration. It wants the following `handler` variable to be a `const` even though it's assigned within `switch` case. Looks like a bug to me.

```
static def(name: string) {
    // [tslint]Unexpected let, use const instead (no-let)
    let handler: Function;
    switch (name) {
        case 'test':
            handler = console.error;
            break;
        default:
            handler = console.warn;
    }

    handler(name);
}
```

Changing it to `const handler: Function` will throw an error in `tsserver`.

```
    const handler: Function;

    switch (name) {
        case 'test':
            // [tsserver] Cannot assign to 'handler' because it's a constant
            handler = console.error;
            break;
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) is a constructor, just like `String`,`Array` etc...

Change it to

```
let handler: () => void;
```

I use `void` because `console.error` and `console.warn` return `undefined`

Comment: You forget the no-let tslint rule

Answer (score -1):

It's not a bug, a constant can't be reassigned, because it's a constant :

```
const a = 1;
a = 2; //gonna log same error as your's
```

For prevent it you can return your result directly on your switch case like :

```
static def(name: string) {
    switch (name) {
        case 'test':
            return console.error;
        default:
            return console.warn;
    }
}
def("test")("Your message to log as error");
def("nottest")("Your message to log as warning");
```

Comment: That's not what the question is about, and a `number` is immutable you cant do `const a = 1; a++`

Comment: Yes you are right about const a, i do the same mistake, i gonna edit it.